# Async Web Service Calls appear to stop being processed, but remote debugger shows otherwise

Tags: .net, web-services, debugging, iis, performancecounter

I fire off about 2k async we service calls that usually take about a 30 to complete in total. Though sometimes they get stuck (visible on performance counter, asp.net, Requests Current when the requests current count does not decrease), if I attach a remote debugger, the web service appears to be being called as I would expect, though never stops being called. I can guarantee I am the only one using this service, how can I find out what is going on here?

This is an intermittent problem, happened about once every 5 attempts.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is network hardware doing its job, protecting against Denial of Service attacks. Could this be an issue? If you are firing off 2,000 requests all at once, most systems would prevent them from happening.

Comment: I connect directly to the web service through the local network (not available externally) and have increased the request queue limit to 10k.

Comment: Do you have logging configured there? Also there is a slight chance in tracing (which by itself will significantly degrade the performance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug with NpgSql Connection pooling. It is fixed in the latest version.